# How to modify a specific row in Flask sqlalchemy ? 'AttributeError'

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi i am building a website for my high school concerning color-blindness. I am suposed to create a test detecting vaguely color-blindness and its different types.

I'm having issues with the database sqlalchemy and flask. Basically I have one page which should display test after test. (`def test`). I have a form on the html part which takes the `result` of the user. Based on this result ifs staments should add or not to variables corresponding to the **specific row** of the current user. For example when I try to change the boolean `fake` with `act_usr = session.get("user")` `act_usr.fake = True`.

However,  `.fake` is not an attribute apperently because when I run the code I have this following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fake'`. Btw, of course I only see the error for the `.fake` attribute but it must be the same for all the others attributes from the database.

Did I make an error while the configuration of the database or my syntax is wrong?
Here is the code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///users.db"
app.secret_key = "hello"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Users(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    fake = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    biz = db.Column(db.Integer)
    d_rouge_vert = db.Column(db.Integer)
    c_rouge_vert = db.Column(db.Integer)
    c_bleu_vert_orange = db.Column(db.Integer)
    dichotomique_protan_deutan = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, name, fake, biz, d_rouge_vert, c_rouge_vert, c_bleu_vert_orange, dichotomique_protan_deutan):
        self.name = name
        self.fake = fake
        self.biz = biz
        self.d_rouge_vert = d_rouge_vert
        self.c_rouge_vert = c_rouge_vert
        self.c_bleu_vert_orange = c_bleu_vert_orange
        self.dichotomique_protan_deutan = dichotomique_protan_deutan


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/home")
def contact():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/test/<num>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/test", defaults={'num': '0'}, methods=["GET", "POST"])
def test(num):
    if num == "0":
        if request.method == "POST":
            nm = request.form["name"]
            session["name"] = nm
            found_user = Users.query.filter_by(name=nm).first()
            session["user"] = found_user
            usr = Users(nm, False, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            db.session.add(usr)
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            return render_template("test.html")

    elif num == "1":
        if request.method == "POST":
            result = request.form.get("result", False)
            # planche n 1
            if result != "12":
                act_usr = session.get("user")
                act_usr.fake = True
                db.session.commit()
        else:
            return render_template("planches/test1.html")

    elif num == "2":
        if request.method == "POST":
            result = request.form["result"]
            # planche n 2
            if result == "3":
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.d_rouge_vert += 1
                db.session.commit()
            elif result == "8":
                pass
            else:
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.biz += 1
                db.session.commit()
        else:
            return render_template("planches/test2.html")

    elif num == "3":
        if request.method == "POST":
            result = request.form["result"]
            # planche n 3
            if result == "5":
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.d_rouge_vert += 1
                db.session.commit()
            elif result == "6":
                pass
            else:
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.biz += 1
                db.session.commit()
        else:
            return render_template("planches/test3.html")

    elif num == "4":
        if request.method == "POST":
            result = request.form.get("result", False)
            # planche n 6
            if result == "2":
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.c_rouge_vert += 1
                db.session.commit()
            elif result == "5":
                pass
            else:
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.biz += 1
                db.session.commit()
        else:
            return render_template("planches/test4.html")

    elif num == "5":
        if request.method == "POST":
            result = request.form["result"]
            # planche n 7
            if result == "5":
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.c_rouge_vert += 1
                db.session.commit()
            elif result == "3":
                pass
            else:
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.biz += 1
                db.session.commit()
        else:
            return render_template("planches/test5.html")

    elif num == "6":
        if request.method == "POST":
            result = request.form["result"]
            # planche n 10
            if result != "2":
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.c_bleu_vert_orange += 1
                db.session.commit()
        else:
            return render_template("planches/test6.html")

    elif num == "7":
        if request.method == "POST":
            result = request.form["result"]
            # planche n 11
            if result != "6":
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.c_bleu_vert_orange += 1
                db.session.commit()
        else:
            return render_template("planches/test7.html")

    elif num == "8":
        if request.method == "POST":
            result = request.form["result"]
            # planche n 22
            if result == "2":
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.dichotomique_protan_deutan += 1
                db.session.commit()
            elif result == "26":
                pass
            else:
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.biz += 1
                db.session.commit()
        else:
            return render_template("planches/test8.html")

    elif num == "9":
        if request.method == "POST":
            result = request.form["result"]
            # planche n 23
            if result == "4":
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.dichotomique_protan_deutan += 1
                db.session.commit()
            elif result == "42":
                pass
            else:
                act_usr = session.get("users")
                act_usr.biz += 1
                db.session.commit()
        else:
            return render_template("planches/test9.html")

    elif num == "fin":
        return render_template("test_fin.html", data=Users.query.all())

    return render_template("planches/test1.html")

@app.route("/infos")
def infos():
    return render_template("infos.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: This error message is telling you that you are handling a variable that is None. I suppose the problem is here: `act_usr = session.get("user")` and the following line. So is the session really set ? I guess not. It's not clear if your session manager really uses the data model and the User object. Are you using [Flask login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering my question. I don't use Flask-login.  I am pretty new to the Flask framework and its extensions, do you know how could I implement Flask-login in my code?

Comment: First of all look at the Python stack trace to identify the exact line causing the error. But I have the impression that your session is not set, which is consistent with the error message you're getting.

Comment: You are right  the problem is here: act_usr = session.get("user"). How could I set the session?